# Which user has answered the most questions on a site?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious and expected this to be a straightforward thing to see.

As in, after https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation, https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors, I expected the following to take me somewhere:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=answers

But that URL doesn't exist, it just redirects to reputation.  So where should I go instead?  If there is no existing place, could this be a feature request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Stack Exchange Data Explorer query, called [Users with most answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197083/users-with-most-answers).

I just entered 10 in the box, to return the top 10 users with the most answers.

Jon Skeet has the most on Stack Overflow, with an amazing 30,253 answers.

To see who is the top answerer on other sites, just type in the site in the *switch sites input box*. And run it again once there.

SEDE also has thousands of other queries that you may find useful, you can even write your own!

Comment: Stack Exchange Data Explorer ... I'm about to lose so much time in this thing.